# Given a number m and k separated by a space print the numbers between m and k

Tags: arrays, for-loop, for-in-loop

`print the numbers between this two numbers`
`let a=[5,7];`
`var temp=[];`

`for(var i=5;i<=8;i++){`

```
  `temp.push(i);`
```

}
`console.log(temp);`=> in this i got all elements[5,6,7,8]  but i need only between number 6&7,here i struck brother

Sample Input :
5 8
Sample Output :
6 7

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. Give it a go and let us know where you get stuck.

Comment: @jsheeran ok brother here i link my code where i struck

Answer (score 0):

```
let a=[5,7]; 
let temp=[];
for(var i = a[0]+1 ; i < a[1]; i++){
    temp.push(i);
}
console.log(temp);
```